# #NUM! error in user defined function

Tags: excel, vba

I made a new function called `length` which tests the count of characters and shows "error result" if the count greater than 5.
However, the result of function is `#NUM`!  If the test is for 5 characters or less the result is shown.

What is wrong?

```
Function length (number as integer)
    If ( Len (CStr (number)) > 5 ) then
        length = "error"
    End if
    If ( Len (Cstr (number)) <6) then
        length = "the count is true"
    End if
End Function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the nature of datatypes this will happen. To be more precise your function will work for values up to, and including, 32,767. Above this it will return #NUM as your `number` can no longer fit inside the integer you force it to be.

If you define your `number` as `Long` datatype it will handle values up to, and including, 2,147,483,647.

For a more detailed explanation of the differences between `Integer` and `Long` you can read the answer from RubberDuck on this post: [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: You could also replace the first end if and the test for <6 and replace with `Else`.  i.e. If it's >5 then error, else it's true.  Also, rather than `length = "error"` you could use `length = CVErr(xlErrNum)` to return an error value (`#NUM!`).  Returning a real error allows you to use `=IFERROR(...)` 
 http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx

Comment: Good suggestions @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: I made the number variable as string. It worked. The wrong was in the type of data. I made the type as long and it also worked perfectly @luuklag